# Changing the default view path for mails in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

is it possible to change the default view path for mails in `Yii 2`?

Reading [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html) and it seems the only way you can change the view path is by calling:

```
setViewPath()
```

..but I don't want to have to call that every time I want to write code to send mail; I would prefer to just be able to change the default view path. Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change default view path in the application config:

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '...', // Insert path here, you can use aliases
    ],
],
```

Comment: I thought it was a private property?

Comment: Yes, it is. But yii\mail\BaseMailer class has setViewPath() method so viewPath property is available for setting via config. Also you can set it like that: Yii::$app->mailer->viewPath = '...'. This is framework core logic.

Comment: Also, you can set "view" component.  'viewPath' => 'themes/basic/views/mail',
            'view' => [
                'theme' => [
                    'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/basic'],
                    'baseUrl' => '@app/themes/basic',
                ],
            ],